# Rails, cannot customize input validation error message

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in the controller and the model. It's for validating whether a model already exists and returning an error message if it does:

Controller

```rb
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end 

  def create

    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    @book.user_id = current_user.id
   
    if @book.save
      redirect_to book_url(@book)
    else 
      @errors = @book.errors.full_messages.first
      redirect_to new_book_url(@errors), alert: @errors

    end
end
```

Model

```rb
  validate :existing_book, on: :create

  def existing_book

    existing_book = Book.find_by('author LIKE ? AND publisher LIKE ?', "#{self.author}", "#{self.publisher}")

    existing_book ||= Book.find_by(name: self.name, date: self.date)

    if existing_book != nil
      errors.add(:name, message: ":This book may already exist.")
    end

  end
```

My problem is:

Upon creating a book that already exists, it first goes to the rails error screen (`No route matches [GET] "/books/new.Name%20:This%20book%20may%20already%20exist."`). Then when I click on back button on the browser, it shows the book creating page with this error message at the bottom: "Name :This book may already exist."

What I would like is:

Upon creating a book that already exists, the screen should remain on that book creating page and show a pop up message. So it should trigger an event. At the least it should stay on the same screen and show a ***correct*** error message (without the "Name," even if not pop up; if I delete ":name" then I get this error: `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)`).

Another problem is that I'm lost on how to do this. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: your question is missing the code in the controller and the form doing the creating, without these there is no way to help you. it's the controller that decides what the user sees after submission.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

> ```
> redirect_to new_book_url(@errors), alert: @errors
> ```

You likely just want to do `render :new` instead (and make sure you're rendering `@errors` in that view)

Comment: As for the other thing, try adding your message to `:base` instead of `:name`

Comment: Thank you. When I try ```render :new, alert: @errors, and create a duplicate book, I get just the same book-creating page. No error messages. How can I make an error message show, and make it a pop-up?

Comment: @superbot: you have to render the errors in the view (this is normally done in the layout file). Check https://www.railstutorial.org/, it covers this.